# Invalid date format (0) when importing datetime values to TSQL

Tags: python, t-sql, pyodbc

I am trying to import datetime values from my pandas dataframe in to the datetime columns of my TSQL Table.

The problem is that I get an error if any of my columns contain a NULL value 'NaT'

see below:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}',
                      host=server,database=dbname,
                      trusted_connection=tcon,
                      user=uname,password=pword)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

df.head()
            Date_1          Date_2
1   2015-07-01 10:53:16 2015-07-01 00:13:09
2   2015-07-03 10:31:16 2015-07-01 16:39:40
3   2015-06-26 14:39:19 2015-06-24 13:56:17

for index, row in df.iterrows():
cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO Table(
Date1,Date2)"""
"""VALUES (?,?)""",
row['Date1'],row['Date2'])

cnxn.commit()
```

> DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0]Invalid date format (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

It has to do with Null values in my datetime columns. When I view the null values in my dataframe they appear as NaT.

I don't know how to import nothing to my TSQL Table.

Answer (score 0):

change the `INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (...)` to `INSERT INTO (...) SELECT ...` with a [NULLIF()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms177562.aspx) statement like so:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}',
                      host=server,database=dbname,
                      trusted_connection=tcon,
                      user=uname,password=pword)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

df.head()
            Date_1          Date_2
1   2015-07-01 10:53:16 2015-07-01 00:13:09
2   2015-07-03 10:31:16 2015-07-01 16:39:40
3   2015-06-26 14:39:19 2015-06-24 13:56:17

for index, row in df.iterrows():
cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO Table(
Date1,Date2)"""
"""SELECT NULLIF(?,'NaT'),NULLIF(?,'NaT') """,
row['Date1'],row['Date2'])

cnxn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`NaT` represents not-a-time, which is the representation of null as a [numpy.datetime64](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) type. The `datetime64` type does not support a value of `None`, which pyodbc expects.

Export the dataframe to dict using [DataFrame.to_dict](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-json) method, which will handle the type conversion from `datetime64` to a [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

```
>>> df
                      Date_1 Date_2
1 2016-04-04 15:50:40.794355   None
2 2016-04-04 15:50:40.794355   None
3 2016-04-04 15:50:40.794355   None
>>> rows = df.to_dict(orient="records")
>>> pprint(rows)
[{'Date_1': Timestamp('2016-04-04 15:50:40.794355'), 'Date_2': None},
 {'Date_1': Timestamp('2016-04-04 15:50:40.794355'), 'Date_2': None},
 {'Date_1': Timestamp('2016-04-04 15:50:40.794355'), 'Date_2': None}]
```

Then loop through the list of dicts (`rows`) and insert with pyodbc as normal. Doesn't require any SQL modifications.