# Insert datetime64 NaT value to SQL date column (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

My MS SQL Server is not accepting the insertion of `NaT` values in a DataFrame column, throwing the following error:

```
pyodbc.DataError: ('22008', u'[22008] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Datetime field overflow (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I've tried inserting the DataFrame into SQL Server using both `pyodbc` and `sqlalchemy` libraries as such:

```py
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy

# pyodbc
cnxn =  pyodbc.connect('DSN=myDSN;UID=myUser;PWD=myPassword;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://MyUser:MyPassword@myDSN")
conn = engine.connect()

sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo.myTable] VALUES(?,?,?,?)"
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
    conn.execute(sql, tuple(row))
```

Example row from DataFrame:

```
(u'John',u'Doe',Timestamp('1978-05-20 00:00:00'),u'Green')
(u'Jane',u'Dawson',NaT,u'Blue')
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411990/invalid-date-format-0-when-importing-datetime-values-to-tsql), `pyodbc` expects `None` values and doesn't know how to handle `numpy.datetime64 NaT` values. Neither answer on that question is working for me. The `NaT` values persist even when I convert my `df` to a `dict` and I can't use `NULLIF` because SQL can't compare a Timestamp object to a string.

Using Python 2.7, is there any way to correctly insert this DataFrame column with `NaT` values into a MS SQL database?

Comment: pandas' to_sql doesn't handle the NaT -> None conversion for you? Can you provide a [mcve] with DDL and version information?

Comment: I need to execute SQL queries row by row because I need to collect the `id` of each inserted row in order to insert related data into a separate table using that `id`. Pandas` `to_sql` does handle the `NaT` to `None` but I need row by row execution so I was using `pyodbc`.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `to_sql` to create a temporary table, then execute `INSERT INTO tbl_target OUTPUT Inserted.id SELECT <columns> FROM #tbl_temp`